# Is aws-sdk-ruby just the newer version of ruby-aws?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I'm following a tutorial that uses the `ruby-aws` gem (https://rubygems.org/gems/ruby-aws), but there is also the `aws-sdk-ruby` gem (https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby) which has been updated a lot more recently.

Did the gem change names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are two different projects, completely un-related.

- `ruby-aws` gem - This is a 3rd party project that is not actively maintained.
- `aws-sdk` gem - This is the official and supported AWS SDK for Ruby. It is available at https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby. It has two major versions. They can be installed and used in the same project because they use different modules. Version 1 uses `AWS::` while version 2 uses `Aws::`. If you are starting a new project, then you should use ~> 2 of `aws-sdk`.